# Strongswan configuration to Cisco

Tags: linux, debian, cisco, ipsec

We have an issue configuring Strongswan to a Cisco router.

The connection is made, but I'm not getting the routing correct.  There are multiple networks behind the router on the remote side (operated by a vendor) and we need to snat the IP's we come from to match their assigned range (so it routes back to us).

```
ipsec status shows the connection:
000 "vpn": 10.10.0.42/32===12.34.56.78[12.34.56.78]:47/0---12.34.56.80...78.56.34.12[78.56.34.12]:47/0===10.10.254.1/32; erouted; eroute owner: #31
000 "vpn":   newest ISAKMP SA: #29; newest IPsec SA: #31; 
000 
000 #31: "vpn" STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 2886s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner
000 #31: "vpn" esp.b3a4e070@78.56.34.12 (0 bytes) esp.6405defd@12.34.56.78 (1872 bytes, 1s ago); tunnel
000 #29: "vpn" STATE_MAIN_I4 (ISAKMP SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 81890s; newest ISAKMP
000 

ip route show table 220
10.10.254.1 via 12.34.56.80 dev eth1  src 10.10.0.42
```

We need to get to segments 10.20.1.0, 10.20.5.0 and 10.20.6.0 and appear to come from 10.10.2.2-254

The internal range we have is 10.1.0.0/32 (iptables snat?)

**Typo -- they want us to appear to come from 10.10.2.2 to 10.10.2.254, had it wrong above.**

Here's the ipsec.conf, I did try multiple segments on the rightsubnet- line, but they never ended up in table 220.  I'm not sure I understand how that route interacts with the normal routes.

```
config setup
       plutodebug=control
       # plutodebug=all
       plutostart=yes
       charondebug=none
       charonstart=no

conn cme-vpn
      ikelifetime=86400s
      keylife=3600s
      rekeymargin=3m
      keyingtries=1
      keyexchange=ikev1
      authby=secret
      ike=3des-md5-modp1024
      esp=3des-md5
      right=78.56.34.12
      rightsubnet=10.10.254.1/32
      rightprotoport=47/0
      left=%defaultroute
      leftsourceip=10.10.0.42
      leftprotoport=47/0
      leftfirewall=yes
      auto=add
      pfs=no
```

Comment: rightsubnet= is only 10.10.254.1/32? Show conf too.

Comment: edited the post to show ipsec.conf